# Can not write an instance of `rosbag::MessageInstance` to a `rosbag::Stream`

Tags: c++, rosbag, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the following peace of code:

```
for (rosbag::View::iterator m=view.begin(); m!=view.end(); m++){
        m->write(stream);
}
```

Where `stream` is a variable of type `rosbag::Stream`. When I run the code I get the error:

```
In file included from *.cpp:6:0:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/rosbag/bag.h: In instantiation of ‘void rosbag::Bag::readMessageDataIntoStream(const rosbag::IndexEntry&, Stream&) const [with Stream = rosbag::BZ2Stream]’:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/rosbag/message_instance.h:170:5:   required from ‘void rosbag::MessageInstance::write(Stream&) const [with Stream = rosbag::BZ2Stream]’
  *.cpp:194:21:   required from here
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/rosbag/bag.h:367:118: error: ‘class rosbag::BZ2Stream’ has no member named ‘advance’
               memcpy(stream.advance(data_size), current_buffer_->getData() + index_entry.offset + bytes_read, data_size);
```

As you can see, internally ros library tries to call a method named `.advance()` on type `rosbag::Stream`. Now if we check the class reference for [`rosbag::Stream`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1Stream.html) we can see that there is no method named `advance()` but rather `advanceOffset(uint64_t nbytes)` which looks like exactly what the library tries to call internally (at least the signature implies that this is what the library needs)

None of the derived classes [`rosbag::UncompressedStream`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1UncompressedStream.html) nor [`rosbag::BZ2Stream`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1BZ2Stream.html) have a method named `advance()`.

Why do I get the above mentioned error and how can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195794/can-not-write-an-instance-of-%60rosbag::messageinstance%60-to-a-%60rosbag::stream%60/) by [abarbarosie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20252/abarbarosie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that's the appropriate way to use the rosbag API to read messages from one bag file and write them to another.

The last time I did this, my code looked something like:

```
rosbag::Bag output("output.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);

rosbag::Bag input("input.bag");
rosbag::View view(input, rosbag::TopicQuery("numbers"));

BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    output.write(m.getTopic(), m.getTime(), m, m.getConnectionHeader());
}

output.close();
input.close();
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abarbarosie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20252/abarbarosie/) on 2014-10-24**:
But that's just copying from one bag file to another... What if you need to interpret the message in your program?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-24**:
I assumed that you were working with MessageInstances because you didn't need to interpret the data, or were doing so elsewhere.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-24**:
The [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) and the [rosbag_storage API](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/) provide an rich API for extracting messages from bag files.